# Multiple aggregate functions with peewee

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I barely know SQL but I have been using `peewee` and so far it has worked really well. I fell upon a problem I'm not sure how to solve. Here are the settings.

I have two tables `A` and `B`. `A`, among other fields, has multiple `B` with a foreign key. `B` has 3 fields (5 in my case, but 3 is the minimum to reproduce):

```
A:
id param_1 ...
0  ...
1  ...
2  ...
```

and

```
B:
id A_key x  y  z
0  0     3. 5. 1
1  0     4. 4. 2
2  1     2. 3. 3
3  1     5. 1. 4
```

**I want to get the `z` which corresponds to the minimum across `x` on one hand, `y` on the other hand, for each `A`.**
Doing so for `x` or `y` is easy: *(Q1)*

```
A.select(fn.MIN(B.x), B.z.alias('z_x')).join(B).group_by(A)
> A_id x  z_x
> 0    3. 1
> 1    2. 3
```

and I can do likewise for B. My question is: what would you do to have both? *(Q2)*

```
???
> A_id x  z_x  y  z_y 
> 0    3. 1    4. 2
> 1    2. 3    1. 4
```

Of course, I tried doing

```
A.select(fn.MIN(B.x), B.z.alias('z_x'), fn.MIN(B.y), B.z.alias('z_y')).join(B).group_by(A)
```

but the column `z_x` is just replaced by `z_y`.

For the SQL specialists out there, *(Q1)* corresponds to

```sql
SELECT MIN("t1"."x"), "t1"."z" FROM "A" AS "t2" INNER JOIN "B" AS "t1" ON ("t1"."A_id" = "t2"."id") GROUP BY "t2"."id"
```

I can also translate a SQL query for *(Q2)* in peewee if someone sees the solution in pure SQL!

Happy for any help, and I can provide more details if needed!

Comment: Can you share the actual SQL you are trying to get? Note you are not including a GROUP BY in any of your queries -- you might try that.

Comment: I was hoping you would see this post! :D 
My mistake, I did include the `group_by` in my code, I edited my post accordingly. 
I do *not* know the actual SQL query which would solve my problem. This is maybe more a SQL issue rather than a peewee one, my apologies if it's the case. I'd simply like to have a way of obtaining *(Q2)*

Comment: hol' up i got you fam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being harder than I thought initially because Sqlite is kinda making the simplified versions of the query work... However they're not *quite* correct. At any rate, the following seems working correctly, at least as far as I understand the question (get the Z's for the min X and min Y, for each A):

```py
class A(Base):
    key = TextField()

class B(Base):
    a = ForeignKeyField(A)
    x = IntegerField()
    y = IntegerField()
    z = IntegerField()

db.create_tables([A, B])

a1 = A.create(key='a1')
a2 = A.create(key='a2')

B.create(a=a1, x=1, y=100, z=10)
B.create(a=a1, x=10, y=10, z=5)
B.create(a=a1, x=100, y=1, z=2)

B.create(a=a2, x=2, y=200, z=20)
B.create(a=a2, x=20, y=20, z=15)
B.create(a=a2, x=200, y=4, z=10)

# The idea is we will create first a query that gets us
# the minimum X for each A (subq).
BX = B.alias()
subq = BX.select(BX.a, fn.MIN(BX.x).alias('minx')).group_by(BX.a)

# Then we want to get the Z's for all rows whose X is
# equal to the minimum X (for each A).
z_for_x = (BX
           .select(BX.a, BX.z, subq.c.minx)
           .join(subq, on=((BX.a == subq.c.a_id) & (BX.x == subq.c.minx)))
           .group_by(BX.a, BX.z))

# Do the same for the Y's.
# First find the minimum Y for each A.
BY = B.alias()
subq = BY.select(BY.a, fn.MIN(BY.y).alias('miny')).group_by(BY.a)

# Then get all Z's for each A whose Y is equal to the
# minimum Y we found.
z_for_y = (BY
           .select(BY.a, BY.z, subq.c.miny)
           .join(subq, on=((BY.a == subq.c.a_id) & (BY.y == subq.c.miny)))
           .group_by(BY.a, BY.z))

# We'll use common table expressions to access these
# two distinct subqueries.
xcte = z_for_x.cte('zforx', columns=['ba', 'bz', 'minx'])
ycte = z_for_y.cte('zfory', columns=['ba', 'bz', 'miny'])

# Then get all A's and their associated minimum X and it's
# corresponding Z, and minimum Y and it's corresponding Z:
q = (A.select(A, xcte.c.minx, xcte.c.bz, ycte.c.miny, ycte.c.bz)
     .join_from(A, xcte, JOIN.INNER, on=(A.id == xcte.c.ba))
     .join_from(A, ycte, JOIN.INNER, on=(A.id == ycte.c.ba))
     .with_cte(xcte, ycte))

# Execute our query:
for row in q.tuples():
    print(row)


#OUTPUT:
# 1, 'a1', 1, 10, 1, 2
# 2, 'a2', 2, 20, 4, 10
```

Explanation of output:

For a1, the minimum X=1 (with z=10), and minimum Y=1 (with z=2)

For a2, the minimum X=2 (with z=20), and minimum Y=4 (with z=10)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer!! That's exactly what I needed. I used `z_for_x = B.select(B.a, fn.MIN(B.x).alias('x'), B.z.alias('z_x')).group_by(B.a)`, as it seems to provide the same results without the need for a subquery (is it what you suggest when you say "Sqlite is kinda making the simplified versions"?). Did not know about this `cte` thing, will clearly remember it!

Comment: Anyway `peewee` is super cool for people like me who overlooked SQL because of the syntax: it makes everything simpler, thanks!

Comment: The catch is that there could be multiple Z values if multiple rows have X=min(X) (and same for Y) -- that's why it is a bit convoluted.